# JSX recommended practice for passing true value prop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have read that if you want to pass a true value, using just the prop name is the recommended approach. What's the reasoning behind this?

```
// recommended, why?
const OtherComponent = () => (
    <SomeComponent isLoggedIn />
);

// not recommended, why?
const OtherComponent = () => (
    <SomeComponent isLoggedIn={true} />
);
```

Comment: I guess it's because the second way is more verbose

Comment: From my experience both are equivalent, with the first approach just being shorter.

Comment: hope this helps https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-default-to-true

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two reasons:

1. It's shorter
2. It more closely mimics [boolean attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes) in HTML

The reason it works is because [props default to true](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-default-to-true), but according to that page, it is *not* a recommended practice to use the shorthand.

So really, as with any code style debate, it's up to you.

Comment: "shorter" is never a good reason. I would say "simpler" or that the value is unnecessary.

Comment: @Sulthan thanks for your comment. I didn't suggest it was a good reason, and arguably it's less "simple" to comprehend since it requires extra knowledge of this special case.